# setText() method returning null in adapter class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am implementing a card view on  a map fragment so on implementing  it, i used two sub classes that extends view holder class.so when i am calling **.setText()** method for the text View of one of the sub classes from the constructor of the main class its returning null i know its due to the scope which it cannot access but how to solve this .This is the code

```
public class Adap1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adap1.ViewHolder> {

    String a121[] = new String[10];
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    FloatingActionButton a1s, a2s, a3s;
    TextView ajk;
     public static final int WeatherVe = 0;
    public static final int ChronoVe = 1;
    int jh=0,moj=0;
    double lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2,degree,s1,speed,l1,l2,lat,lon;


    public Adap1(String a121[])
    {
        this.a121 = a121;
    }


    public Adap1(double l1,double l2,double lat1,double lat2)
    {
        this.l1=l1;
        this.lat1=lat1;
        this.l2=l2;
        this.lat2=lat2;
        s1 = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(l1, l2, lat1, lat2);
        System.out.println(l1+" "+l2);
        System.out.println(lat1+""+lat2);
        speed=s1%(0.0019);
        ajk.setText(d);//error is coming here when i am accesing text view of clima class   
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            super(v);
        }
    }
    public class WeatherVe extends ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemTitle;
        ImageView acv;
        public TextView itemg;
        public WeatherVe(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            itemTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ass);
            itemg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ass1);
        }
    }
    public class Clima extends ViewHolder
    {
        public Clima(View v)
        {
            super(v);
            a1s = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.as);
            a2s = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.as1);
           ajk=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.olx);
            System.out.println(ajk);
            System.out.println("Initialization");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v;
        if (viewType == WeatherVe) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card_lay12, parent, false);
            return new WeatherVe(v);
        }
        else
        {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.card123, parent, false);
            return new Clima(v);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == WeatherVe) {
            WeatherVe hsolder = (WeatherVe) holder;
            hsolder.itemTitle.setText(a121[position]);
            avd = hsolder.itemTitle.getContext();
            hsolder.itemg.setText(a121[position + 1]);
        } else if(holder.getItemViewType()==ChronoVe)
        {
            Clima hags = (Clima) holder;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    }
```

In the logcat it is showing

> **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null
>   object` reference**

please tell me how to acces that text view from that constructor.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: that is beacause your input data is null and you set that in textview. Put Log to check if there is some value retrurning or not.

Comment: I didn't have a proper look at your code, so you'll know all the details better, but in any case `ajk=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.olx);` needs to run before `ajk.setText(d);`. Otherwise you get this `NullPointerException`. (A proper answer would require a more careful look at the code.)

Comment: The method is not returning anything. SetText is a void method...

Comment: Where is this `TextView`? Is there a reason why you are doing `setText` inside the `RecyclerView` adapters constructor?

Comment: i have passed values from another class and received those from the constructor and i want to print it in text view of clima class

Comment: Where is the variable `d` declared?

Comment: sry i have deleted it in editing but i have tested it with putting some String variable and printing it but same error

Comment: @saipavan Why don't you do the `setText` in the `onBindViewHolder`?

Comment: because that value which i want to print in the textView will change every 5sec because it is triggered by location Listener in such a case constructor must me called every time if there is an alternative please tell me

Comment: You could write a method that updates the location (not constructor). Update the value call `notifyDataSetChanged` and set it in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: calling the setText method in onBindViewHolder will fix the problem but i cant call onBindViewHolder  continously

Comment: kk i will try ur solution

Comment: u mean there must be a method in onBindViewHolder instead of constructor which i should call

Comment: can u post the code how it should be done plss

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the constructor of the adapter.

```
ajk.setText(d);
```

That isn't where it goes (because the view is clearly null there, and you can't assign it at that point). Also remove the member variable for the textview from the adapter class. That isn't necessary.

Notice these lines?

```
WeatherVe hsolder = (WeatherVe) holder;
hsolder.itemTitle.setText(a121[position]);
avd = hsolder.itemTitle.getContext();
hsolder.itemg.setText(a121[position + 1]);
```

Looks similar to what you're trying to do, yes?

Set the text of the `Clima hags` holder there after you move the TextView into the Clima class

---

Also, the adapter should know nothing about these, so remove those as well

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
```

---

I'd recommend that you read about [heterogeneous views in a RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) since that's what you have

Comment: if i want to print the text for one time i would have used the **.setText()** method in the onBindView holder but i will be updating that text every 5 sec to be more specific the onLocationChanged() method in other class will be sending values to the adapter class through constructor every 5sec

Comment: Sounds like that textview does not deserve to be in the adapter, then, but outside of the ListView

Comment: yeah got it instead of putting that text view in the card layout i will be putting it in other layout which will solve the problem